# Dealing with data inside TFIDF Sparevector or saving it to Dataframe or external file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am calculating TF and IDF using HashingTF and IDF of Pyspark using the following code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.mllib.feature import HashingTF
from pyspark.mllib.feature import IDF

sc = SparkContext()

# Load documents (one per line).
documents = sc.textFile("random.txt").map(lambda line: line.split(" "))

hashingTF = HashingTF()
tf = hashingTF.transform(documents)
tf.cache()

idf = IDF(minDocFreq=2).fit(tf)
tfidf = idf.transform(tf)
```

The question is: I can print tfidf on the screen using collect() method but how can I access specific data inside it or save the whole tfidf vectorspace to an external file or Dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HashingTF` and `IDF` return `RDD` where each element is `pyspark.mllib.linalg.Vector` (`org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector` in Scala)*. It means that:

- you can access individual indices using simple indexing. For example:

  ```
  documents = sc.textFile("README.md").map(lambda line: line.split(" "))
  tf = HashingTF().transform(documents)
  idf = IDF().fit(tf)
  tfidf = idf.transform(tf)

  v = tfidf.first()
  v
  ## SparseVector(1048576, {261052: 0.0, 362890: 0.0, 816618: 1.9253})

  type(v)
  ## pyspark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector

  v[0]
  ## 0.0
  ```
- can be saved directly to text file. [`Vectors`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=vectors#pyspark.mllib.linalg.Vectors) provide meaningful string representation and `parse` method which can be used to restore original structure.

  ```
  from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors

  tfidf.saveAsTextFile("/tmp/tfidf")
  sc.textFile("/tmp/tfidf/").map(Vectors.parse)
  ```
- can be placed in a `DataFrame`

  ```
  df = tfidf.map(lambda v: (v, )).toDF(["features"])

  ## df.printSchema()
  ## root
  ## |-- features: vector (nullable = true)

  df.show(1, False)
  ## +-------------------------------------------------------------+
  ## |features                                                     |
  ## +-------------------------------------------------------------+
  ## |(1048576,[261052,362890,816618],[0.0,0.0,1.9252908618525775])|
  ## +-------------------------------------------------------------+
  ## only showing top 1 row
  ```
- [`HashingTF`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=vectors#pyspark.mllib.feature.HashingTF) is irreversible so it cannot be used to extract information about specific tokens. See [How to get word details from TF Vector RDD in Spark ML Lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32285699/1560062)

Comment: This greatly helps @zero323 , but I do not want to save it as a complex structure.
The problem remains: how to extract/access (in your example) the part [261052,362890,816618] and part [0.0,0.0,1.9252908618525775] to save them separately or to make some calculations on them.