# Linking the resulting TFIDF sparse vectors to the original documents in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, tf-idf, apache-spark-mllib

I am calculating the TFIDF using Spark with Python using the following code:

```
    hashingTF = HashingTF()
    tf = hashingTF.transform(documents)
    idf = IDF().fit(tf)
    tfidf = idf.transform(tf)
    for k in tfidf.collect(): 
      print(k)
```

I got the following results for three documents:

```
    (1048576,[558379],[1.43841036226])
    (1048576,[181911,558379,959994],  [0.287682072452,0.287682072452,0.287682072452])
    (1048576,[181911,959994],[0.287682072452,0.287682072452])
```

Assuming that I have thousands of documents, how to link the resulting TFIDF sparse vectors to the original documents knowing that I don't care about reversing the Hash-keys to the original terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both `documents` and `tfidf` have the same shape (number of partitions, number of elements per partition) and there no operations which require shuffle you can simply `zip` both RDDs:

```
documents.zip(tfidf)
```

Reversing HashingTF is [for an obvious reason](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32285699/1560062) not possible.

Comment: I can control the number of partitions but how can I control the number of elements per partition?

Comment: You cannot. Well... You can apply different low level transformations but there is no way to do it directly. That is why `zip` is applicable only in some limited cases like this. Otherwise you need unique identifiers and join.

Comment: Ah,identifiers and join, a very good point for me and I have an identifier with my documents. but how can I enforce the code above to include it inside the tfidf RDD?