# OneHotEncoder with input being an array

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to extract the feature from my raw data.

My raw data is a `Seq[String]`.

I want to turn this into a `OneHot` encoding with several `1` instead of only one but it seems that the spark ml https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#onehotencoderestimator is only accepting a single `String` as input.

Maybe I am blind, but I can't seem to find one which accept a list of string.

Thank you.

Comment: Use `CountVectorizer` or `HashingTF` in binary variant?

Comment: So I used `HashingTF` but how are you able to go back from the encoding to the token ? I am going to take a look at `CountVectorizer`

Comment: If you need details go with `CountVectorizer` - [How to get word details from TF Vector RDD in Spark ML Lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32285699/8371915)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @[user8371915](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8371915/user8371915)

Reading
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html#countvectorizer
it seems like it is exactly what I need.

More info: 
[How to get word details from TF Vector RDD in Spark ML Lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32285699/how-to-get-word-details-from-tf-vector-rdd-in-spark-ml-lib)