# How to map TFIDF values to original words

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, tf-idf

I've followed [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#tf-idf) example for computing TFIDF of each word in my documents. However, my final output looks something like this (which is obviously okay since I am using HashingTF):

```
(262144,[24856,31066,96984,119418,143328,176968,193347,223999,243191,245270,250475],[2.3513752571634776,1.9459101490553132,1.9459101490553132,2.3513752571634776,1.4350845252893227,2.3513752571634776,2.3513752571634776,1.9459101490553132,3.8918202981106265,1.9459101490553132,2.3513752571634776])
(262144,[21028,31066,71524,72609,116873,140075,142830,155149,222394,226568,245044],[1.9459101490553132,1.9459101490553132,1.6582280766035324,2.3513752571634776,2.3513752571634776,1.9459101490553132,1.9459101490553132,2.3513752571634776,1.9459101490553132,1.252762968495368,1.9459101490553132])
```

Does there exist any API which matches word to its TFIDF value, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get word details from TF Vector RDD in Spark ML Lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32285699/how-to-get-word-details-from-tf-vector-rdd-in-spark-ml-lib)

Comment: @user10938362 this probably may help. Thanks, will try.