# How Spark HashingTF works

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, tf-idf, apache-spark-ml

I am new to Spark 2. 
I tried Spark tfidf example

```
sentenceData = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0.0, "Hi I heard about Spark")
], ["label", "sentence"])

tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="sentence", outputCol="words")
wordsData = tokenizer.transform(sentenceData)


hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="words", outputCol="rawFeatures", numFeatures=32)
featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)

for each in featurizedData.collect():
    print(each)
```

It outputs

```
Row(label=0.0, sentence=u'Hi I heard about Spark', words=[u'hi', u'i', u'heard', u'about', u'spark'], rawFeatures=SparseVector(32, {1: 3.0, 13: 1.0, 24: 1.0}))
```

I expected that in `rawFeatures` I will get term frequencies like `{0:0.2, 1:0.2, 2:0.2, 3:0.2, 4:0.2}`. Because terms frequency is:

```
tf(w) = (Number of times the word appears in a document) / (Total number of words in the document)
```

In our case is : `tf(w) = 1/5 = 0.2` for each word, because each word apears once in a document.
If we imagine  that output `rawFeatures` dictionary contains word index as key, and number of word appearances in a document as value, why key `1` is equal to `3.0`? There no word that appears in a document 3 times.
This is confusing for me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR;** It is just a simple hash collision. `HashingTF` takes `hash(word) % numBuckets` to determine the bucket and with very low number of buckets like here collisions are to be expected. In general you should use much higher number of buckets or, if collisions are unacceptable, `CountVectorizer`.

In detail. `HashingTF` by default uses Murmur hash. `[u'hi', u'i', u'heard', u'about', u'spark']` will be hashed to `[-537608040, -1265344671, 266149357, 146891777, 2101843105]`. If you [follow the source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/60022bfd65e4637efc0eb5f4cc0112289c783147/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/feature/HashingTF.scala#L161-L163) you'll see that the implementation is equivalent to:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String
import org.apache.spark.unsafe.hash.Murmur3_x86_32.hashUnsafeBytes

Seq("hi", "i", "heard", "about", "spark")
  .map(UTF8String.fromString(_))
  .map(utf8 => 
    hashUnsafeBytes(utf8.getBaseObject, utf8.getBaseOffset, utf8.numBytes, 42))
```

```
Seq[Int] = List(-537608040, -1265344671, 266149357, 146891777, 2101843105)
```

When you take [non-negative modulo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41785089) of these values you'll get `[24, 1, 13, 1, 1]`:

```scala
List(-537608040, -1265344671, 266149357, 146891777, 2101843105)
  .map(nonNegativeMod(_, 32))
```

```
List[Int] = List(24, 1, 13, 1, 1)
```

Three words from the list (i, about and spark) hash to the same bucket, each occurs once, hence the result you get.

Related:

- [What hashing function does Spark use for HashingTF and how do I duplicate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31540164/6910411)
- [How to get word details from TF Vector RDD in Spark ML Lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32285699/6910411)